# ControlsFX: Validation result

Tags: validation, javafx, controlsfx

I want to do some validation in `JavaFx` using `ControlsFX`. my code is like this:

```
ValidationSupport support = new ValidationSupport();
boolean isValid = true;
if(textField.getText().trim().isEmpty()) isValid = false;
support.registerValidator(testField, Validator.createEmptyValidator("This field is required!"));
```

My question is if is it possible to omit the `if` condition and extract whether or not the `textField` is empty from the validation support

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `isValid` variable and the `if` statement aren't really doing anything. The `ValidationSupport` contains an observable [`invalid` property](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/validation/ValidationSupport.html#invalidProperty) with which you can register listeners:

```
support.invalidProperty().addListener((obs, wasInvalid, isNowInvalid) -> {
    if (isNowInvalid) {
        System.out.println("Invalid");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Valid");
    }
});
```

or (perhaps more conveniently) register bindings:

```
Button okButton = new Button("OK");
okButton.disableProperty().bind(support.invalidProperty());
```

This last code snippet will ensure the `okButton` is only enabled if the text field is not empty.

Comment: how to apply this if I have to many TextFields to validate (my if condition was made so I could prevent a dialog window from closing)

Comment: Just register a validator with `support` for each of the text fields.